# Command line way to generate report pdf for load runner

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I am running the load runner tests using command line. Is there a way by which i can generate the pdf analysis report automatically. I dont want to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

See templates for Analysis.   Set your controller to run analysis automatically upon conclusion of your tests.

Comment: I was asking if we have a way to this programmatically. I am trying to create a framework that would perform the performance run and then send out an email with the analysis.

Comment: Yes, this is do-able.  Probably your fastest path is to use the Jenkins integration and then the Jenkins ability to notify on test results.   Otherwise, use the command line to run the test, the analysis with your template will be kicked off automatically, outputting the PDF. You can then use command line tools to send the PDF to a notification list